# Firebase task.getResult().getData(); always returning null. (asynchronous problem?)

Tags: typescript, firebase, asynchronous, async-await, google-cloud-functions

My guess is that there's a problem because i'm not returning the right promise?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.
Here is my program task:

```
(...)                 
                    .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                               Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) task.getResult().getData();//<-- this always returns null
                                return (String) result.get("userID");
                            }
                            else return "Task FAILED";
                        }
                    });
        }
```

And here is my cloud code:

```
export const createCompany = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {

    const email = data.email //data.key
    const password = data.password

    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: email,
        emailVerified: true,
        password: password,
        disabled: false
    })
    .then(async function(userRecord) {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        return setAsCompany(email).then(() =>{
           console.log("Company Role Granted", userRecord.email);
           return {userID : userRecord.uid};
       })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
    });

  });

  async function setAsCompany(email: string): Promise<void>{
    const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);
    console.log("ADDED AS COMPANY");

        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid,{
            company: true,
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you are not correctly returning the Promises chain. Also you mix `async/await` and `then()` method calls, which is not really recommended. The following should do the trick:

```
export const createCompany = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {

        const email = data.email //data.key
        const password = data.password

        const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
            email: email,
            emailVerified: true,
            password: password,
            disabled: false
        });

        await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, {
            company: true,
        });

        return { userID: userRecord.uid };

    } catch (error) {
        // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked , now I have a function that triggers when a user is created and it overwrides those custom claims , how can I prevent this?